# Cannot read property 'fetchSpec' of undefined, getting this error when doing `npm ci` i have node v14.20

Tags: node.js, npm, package-lock.json

I used `npm ci` in my local system, and got the error

```
Cannot read property 'fetchSpec' of undefined
```

Answer (score -1):

As `npm ci` was failing
 I removed `package-lock.json` file and did `npm i`. Installation was successful